# Webpack 5 images not found when importing to a module

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a very simple Webpack 5 config, and I am trying to import images for use in my React app. I am able to import the image and use it without Webpack complaining:

```
import SomeImage from 'assets/some-image-jpg'
...
<img src={SomeImage} />
```

However, the image is not found in the browser. I am using webpack-manifest-plugin and the devServer option `writeToDisk` to serve the assets via Django. The JS and CSS work as expected.

```
const path = require('path');
const { WebpackManifestPlugin } = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './front/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'index-bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './local-static'),
    publicPath: '/',
    assetModuleFilename: 'img/[hash][ext][query]',
  },
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
    disableHostCheck: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, "front"),
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'css/[name].css' }),
    new WebpackManifestPlugin({ publicPath: './' }),
  ],
};
```

**EDIT:** Sample output of mainfest.json file:

```
{
  "main.css": "./css/main.css",
  "main.js": "./index-bundle.js",
  "main.jpg": "./img/fbf8476a272a27c10e80.jpg",
  "front/assets/no-image.jpg": "./img/fbf8476a272a27c10e80.jpg"
}
```

"front" is the name of the folder where the source files are stored.

**EDIT 2:** Contents of output folder:

```
├── css
│   └── main.css
├── img
│   └── fbf8476a272a27c10e80.jpg
├── index-bundle.js
└── manifest.json
```

Comment: From the `asset/resource` documentation looks like it returns a JSON. What do you get from logging `SomeImage`?

Comment: I see the url and hashed filename of the image - `/img/fbf8476a272a27c10e80.jpg`, which I believe is correct.

Comment: Looks like `writeToDisk` copies your assets to your `output.path`.

Comment: Correct - but if the JS file and CSS files load successfully, shouldn't this work? I assume if there was an issue with the paths, I would see an error in the Webpack console.

Comment: If you go into your `local-static` folder, do you find the image file somwhere?

Comment: Yes - I have added the tree output of the output folder to the post.

Comment: If you can provide a repository reproducing the problem I would gladly test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your image appears to exist, only it has been renamed with the with a hash key prefix. This is to get around image cache issues when the file name doesn't change, but the image has. Normally the plugin is smart enough to fix most but **NOT** all of the references to the rename.

To check whether your image file is actually being written to disk you can temporarily alter the *assetModuleFilename* key to use the original name and file extension as shown in the section below. If your image file is unlikely to change you can probably make this change permanent.
You should now hopefully see the file in the browser!

Otherwise workaround by manually replacing the new hashed name of the image referenced in your config or other files where necessary. A map file *manifest.json* of all hash entries can be generated by the plugin automatically

example:

```
  output: {
    publicPath:"", // default is "auto"
    path: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    clean: true,
    assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]'
  },
```

**Warning**!
Do not put a period mark(.) between the substitutions in the *assetModuleFilename* key as is done in the *filename* key or you may get a file not found error.